How do I configure Airflow's Helm Chart to Authenticate Git-Sync with a Gitlab Access Token?
Airflow allows for two types of documented access to git:

ssh
username/password

Github now requires SSH only; and in the case of a local deployment of Gitlab, an available security configuration is 2FA or token-based authentication.
In my org, token-based authentication is by far the easier of the two methods I might be able to authenticate (ssh or tokens), but I am not sure I'll be able to do it with ssh.  I am pretty sure the path forward is with tokens.

This question amounts to: how do I configure airflow to authenticate with git using an access token?
And I say this having successfully configured airflow on kubernetes to use the USERNAME/PASSWORD method for GITSYNC, and generating the following error message, which is familiar to me in other contexts:
{
  "logger": "",
  "ts": "2024-08-30 21:52:28.182461",
  "caller": {
    "file": "main.go",
    "line": 784
  },
  "msg": "too many failures, aborting",
  "error": "Run(git ls-remote -q https://gitlab...../my-path/my-private-repo.git the-branch the-branch^{}): exit status 128: { stdout: \"\", stderr: \"remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab........./help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied\\nfatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab........./my-path/my-private-repo.git/'\" }",
  "failCount": 1
}


This was an XY problem..  The way you clone with a token using gitlab is:
git clone https://oauth2:token@gitlab.com/project.git


I had the same problem. You need to add Personal access token (base64) to your git credentials under secrets. If you need more help you are free to ask.
Happy Coding

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
